# Nuget Packages are not restoring in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, nuget-package-restore, azureportal, azure-durable-functions

I have created a durable function to call the holiday API. For that, I have created one Activity function. to call API using the `RestSharp`, I have added `RestSharp` NuGet package in `function.proj` file but it is not working as it throwing error:

**System logs**

Here is the function.proj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="108.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Code**

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask"

using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using RestSharp;

public static async Task<string> Run(string year)
{   
    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest($"https://public-holiday.p.rapidapi.com/{year}/US", Method.Get);
    request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "4044d6bf21msh7f85c4f22fd1584p1e8e2bjsn43f3a0d088cb");
    request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "public-holiday.p.rapidapi.com");
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    return response.Content;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code in the question!

Comment: @HariKrishna I have added the code in question, also you can see it in a given image.

Comment: I can see in a given image but i cannot the code from image to check where is the fault! In Stack Overflow, the code snippets and errors should be posted in the code/text format!

Comment: @HariKrishna Okay got it.

Answer (score 0):

- Created the Azure Durable Function .NET 6 in VS 2022 > Modified the Function code like yours.
- Created the Rapid API Application for generating the API Key.

This is the default code generated after creating of .NET 6 Durable Functions and modified the Activity and Orchestration code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using RestSharp;

namespace KrishAzDFunApp01
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHelloAsync), "2022"));

            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(SayHelloAsync))]
        public static async Task<string> SayHelloAsync([ActivityTrigger] string year)
        {
            var client = new RestClient();
            var request = new RestRequest($"https://public-holiday.p.rapidapi.com/{year}/US", Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "<get api key from rapidapi.com site>");
            request.AddHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", "public-holiday.p.rapidapi.com");
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            return response.Content;

        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);
            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Running Locally:
[image]

[image]

After deploying to Portal Function App > Select **`Function1_HttpStart`** > Copy ***Function URL*** and paste in the new tab of the browser > Click on **`statusQueryGetUri`**

[image]

Comment: That will probably work because you have deployed it after created in visual studio, in my case I am directly creating a function in the azure portal.